# What ship is this and which military campaign?

Tags: military, identification, ships

On back of card, Army Transport USS Maricu - life on board - nothing to do. I can not find any information on this ship. Is it WWI or WWII?

[image]

The reverse of the card is shown below:

[image: Reverse of postcard]

Answer (score 47):

Postcards produced on Kodak Professional AZO paper had 'AZO stamp boxes' on the reverse.  The [style of these boxes varied over time](https://web.archive.org/web/20230521152145/http://www.edinphoto.org.uk/0_PC_0/0_post_card_history_-_stamp_boxes.htm).

In this case, we have four triangles in the corners of the stamp box, two 'up' and two 'down'. This suggests that the card was produced in the date-range 1918-1930.

---

The ship name on the reverse appears to be '*USS Marica*'.  A search for the USS Marica found [another image of this card](https://www.shipscribe.com/usnaux/ww1/ships/id4031.htm), with the caption:

> **Sea sick Soldiers on the ship's deck, while they were en route home from France in mid-1919**.
>
> The original image is printed on post card ("AZO") stock.

which matches the dating from the AZO stamp box.

Comment: the uniforms, especially the hats, corroborate the timing as being WW1 era or slightly later.

Comment: According to [HistoryCentral.com](https://www.historycentral.com/navy/Transport/marica.html) the picture must have been taken between June 9 and September 12 1919.

Comment: I feel sick just looking at them.